# GoogleMap V2 loads map randomly android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have implemented Google Map V2 in my application, Everything works just fine.
Checked on 2-3 mobiles and tabs it runs perfectly,

But it runs for 10 to 15 times a day on single device.,after that it does not load map on same device and gives following error.

05-06 07:17:41.866: E/Google Maps Android API(17217): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.

In short, sometimes it displays map and sometimes it does not.

I m using map key generated from android debug key.

Please suggest some solutions for this.

My Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ocatalog.mapdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.ocatalog.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ocatalog.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA9E-oCIM2d5rlhxnsJf66Bly57JXpkiKI" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.ocatalog.mapdemo.MapDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: That seems very strange, do you have any clues as to why it stops working? Could you post your AndroidManifest.xml and the code containing your GoogleMap?

Comment: I am having the Same problem while loading maps on continuous basis, seems like there is some restrictions put on the Key generated from the Debug.Keystore, not sure though.

Comment: No clues..but above is my Manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem, the maps are running OK on multiple devices, but randomly show a blank screen, sometimes for days.

When I debug the code I can see that all actions like adding markers, overlays, etc. are executed properly.
Also, no idea if this is related, but the Geocoder seems to be working correctly in the meanwhile, so it is definitely not related to an Google Services connectivity issue(or is it?).

Besides, the map also works fine offline and the cache data is stored properly (well, most of the time that is).

Clearing my app's cache and data also doesn't help. Nor does doing so for the Google Services app.
However, reinstalling the application seems to fix it for most of the time, but does not prevent it from reoccurring.

Comment: hey...after some experiments I came to know that ..it was due to server connectivity problem, otherwise rest of my code was ok.

Comment: What version of the API are you using? I haven't seen this issue since late 2014...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `permission` in your `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

There are `Google Maps API v2` and `Google Maps Android API v2`.

You should use `Google Maps Android API v2`.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, But I have already added that permission, My map runs perfectly in all mobiles but after certain mutiple runs of same code it gives above error.

Comment: Google map V2 api. I have created map key from the hash key (my keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "home\niket\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android)

Comment: I m using Google Maps Android API v2.